# 1. Resource Definition is Malformed

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-iam, aws-ssm

0

I am writing a cloud formation template that install SSM in EC2. but when i upload the template in Cfn. I got the error called Resource Definition is Malformed.

```
Description: This Template Create an EC2 in public subnet with SSM.

Resources:
  SSMIAMRole:
  Type: AWS::IAM::Role
  Properties:
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
      Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service:
              - ec2.amazonaws.com
          Action:
            - sts:AssumeRole
    ManagedPolicyArns:
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore


  EC2InstanceProfile:
  Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
  Properties:
    Path: /
    Roles:
      - !Ref SSMIAMRole

  Instance:
  Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
  Properties:
    IamInstanceProfile: !Ref EC2InstanceProfile
    ImageId: ami-0aa7d40eeae50c9a9
    VPCId: vpc-04ef73b29000f4f54 
    SubnetId: subnet-0699037225107e8b2
    InstanceType: !FindInMap [EnvironmentToInstanceType, !Ref EnvironmentType, InstanceType]
    Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: !Join [ '-', [ !Ref EnvironmentType, webserver ] ]
```

I am not sure what else to try. Here is the template I am working with..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your YAML indentation is wrong.  You should indent `Type` below the resource name, e.g.,

```
Resources:
  SSMIAMRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties: ...
```